# Identifying original key of each element in a combination list result of a product

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this:

```
d = {'o1': [1, 2, 3], 'o2': [0, -1], 'o3': [7, 8, 10, 11]}
```

And I want all combinations of each element in every list. For that I am using a product:

```
itertools.product(*d.values())
```

Going through each combination yields:

```
(7, 0, 1)
(7, 0, 2)
(7, 0, 3)
```

I need to keep track of the original list of each element in the resulting combination list. I need to be able to tell that `7` belongs to `'o3'`, `0` to `'o2'` and `1` to `'o1'`. Elements are not unique.

How could I go about this?

I have tried this:

```
r = [[(k, x) for x in v] for k, v in d.iteritems()]
itertools.product(*r)
```

It yields:

```
(('o3', 7), ('o2', 0), ('o1', 1))
(('o3', 7), ('o2', 0), ('o1', 2))
(('o3', 7), ('o2', 0), ('o1', 3))
```

But I don't think it's too elegant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `collections.OrderedDict` to specify the order of your values.

Below are a couple of ways you can do this.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

od1 = OrderedDict(sorted(d.items()))

od2 = OrderedDict([('o1', [1, 2, 3]), ('o2', [0, -1]), ('o3', [7, 8, 10, 11])])
```

Then when you run `itertools.product` the order of iteration will be in line with your `OrderedDict` order.

Answer (score 0):

I think by inverting the dictionary key value pair you can refer to the reverted dictionary later conveniently:

```
dd = dict()

for key, val in d.items():
  for element in val:
    if not dd.get(element):
      dd[element] = list()
    dd[element].append(key)

dd
# {1: ['o1'], 2: ['o1'], 3: ['o1'], 0: ['o2'], -1: ['o2'], 7: ['o3'], 8: ['o3'], 10: ['o3'], 11: ['o3']}

dd[1]
# ['o1']
```

Since the values in the original dictionary is not unique, you want the new dictionary’s values to be lists.

Edit:
In order to get output aligned with product:

```
p = list(product (*d.values())
[tuple(dd[i] for i in val) for val in p]
# [(['o1'], ['o2'], ['o3']), (['o1'], ['o2'], ['o3']), (['o1'], ['o2'], ['o3']), (['o1'], ['o2'], ['o3']), (['o1'], ['o2'], ['o3']), (['o1'], ['o2'], ['o3']), (['o1'], ['o2'], ['o3']), (['o1'], ['o2'], ['o3']), (['o1'], ['o2'], ['o3']), (['o1'], ['o2'], ['o3']), (['o1'], ['o2'], ['o3']), (['o1'], ['o2'], ['o3']), (['o1'], ['o2'], ['o3']), (['o1'], ['o2'], ['o3']), (['o1'], ['o2'], ['o3']), (['o1'], ['o2'], ['o3']), (['o1'], ['o2'], ['o3']), (['o1'], ['o2'], ['o3']), (['o1'], ['o2'], ['o3']), (['o1'], ['o2'], ['o3']), (['o1'], ['o2'], ['o3']), (['o1'], ['o2'], ['o3']), (['o1'], ['o2'], ['o3']), (['o1'], ['o2'], ['o3'])]
```

You can use the same indexing to get the key-value pair